# Ruby on Rails simple_format restrictions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rail's `simple_format` to take in details from a user. I want them to be able to add  paragraphs, line breaks, paragraphs, anchor tags, etc. but I want to restrict some HTML tags–specifically images.

Does anyone know how I could implement this?

Also, I've looked at the documentation but I can't seem to find which HTML tags are allowed using `simple_format`. Is anyone aware of a list somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sanitize` helper built in rails:

```
sanitize(html, tags: %w(a b i u strong em img p br)
```

It will allow only specific set of tags.